# cannot open /include/cassandra.h (No such file or directory)

Tags: php, cassandra, pecl

I am trying to install the cassandra driver for php using

```
pecl install cassandra
```

It fails with:

> cannot open /include/cassandra.h (No such file or directory)

can anybody help? I did install the cpp-drivers before.

Comment: Error seems clear to me.

Comment: `find . -name cassandra.h -print; in my case i found the cassandra.h in the directory src/debug/cassandra-cpp-driver-2.2.0/include/cassandra.h since I have installed 2.2.0 cpp driver. I copied the cassandra.h into /usr/include. The error vanished and I could build the driver.Since the cassandra.h is missing in the /usr/include do the following #cd /usr;find . -name cassandra.h -print; in my case i found the cassandra.h in the directory src/debug/cassandra-cpp-driver-2.2.0/include/cassandra.h since I have installed 2.2.0 cpp driver. I copied the cassandra.h into /usr/include.`

Comment: Extracted from a deleted stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516260/datastax-php-driver-fatal-error-cassandra-h-no-such-file-or-directory